# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Application' is undefined

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I was following the "HelloWorldWithPages" tutorial from

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Application' is undefined

It occurs right here: `return nav.navigate(Application.navigator.home);`

Here is the full file:

default.js

```
// For an introduction to the Navigation template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232506
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var nav = WinJS.Navigation;

    app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }

            // Save the previous execution state. 
            WinJS.Application.sessionState.previousExecutionState =
                args.detail.previousExecutionState;

            if (app.sessionState.history) {
                nav.history = app.sessionState.history;
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
                if (nav.location) {
                    nav.history.current.initialPlaceholder = true;
                    return nav.navigate(nav.location, nav.state);
                } else {
                    return nav.navigate(Application.navigator.home);
                }
            }));
        }
    });

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. If you need to 
        // complete an asynchronous operation before your application is 
        // suspended, call args.setPromise().
        app.sessionState.history = nav.history;
    };

    app.start();
})();
```

Please let me know if I need to show the code from any other file too. I am unable to understand why this problem keeps coming.

Comment: This simply means that the global symbol "Application" is undefined. Elsewhere you refer to `WinJS.Application`. Maybe that's what you need to do in this case.

Comment: @Pointy WinJS.Application is not correct. "home" is not a valid property of WinJS.Application.navigator.